# Get pointer address from file

Tags: c

My purpose is to write the starting address of the malloced area to the file, then assign a new pointer to read this address from the file so that this pointer can point to the same address. Unfortunately, I do not get the right result.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct log_t{
  char data[0];
};

int main(void)
{
  FILE *fp;

  fp = fopen("example.cfg", "w");

  if (fp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  struct log_t* log = malloc(sizeof(struct log_t));
  int node_id = 0;

  fprintf(fp, "Node%d's malloc address is %p\n", node_id, log);

  int i = 0;
  struct log_t* read_log;
  while(fscanf(fp, "Node%d's malloc address is %x", &i, &read_log) == 2){
  }
  printf("read_log points to %p\n", read_log);

  free(log);
  fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is fairly brittle and not very well defined:

- It's not clear what the `%p` specifier produces (you seem to expect a hexadecimal number but the standard doesn't guarantee that)
- It's not clear that `%x` will match the size of the pointer on your machine (`%x` wants an `unsigned int` which is not enough for pointers on many implementations).

That said, I believe your immediate problem is simpler: you need to rewind the file (either with `rewind` or with `fseek`) before you can read what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work very well, or rather it will only work *in the current process that actually allocated the memory and wrote the pointer to the file*.

If you make another program that reads and parses the address, it will not point to any allocated memory, leading to *undefined behavior* if you try to dereference the pointer (i.e. actually use the structure).

Memory and allocations are unique for each process, two different processes (even processes created from the same program) have no guarantee that they will have the same memory map, or even be loaded at the same address (due to [address space randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)).

Comment: It's the same process. What the OP is doing is brittle and pointless but it should work.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Thanks for your suggestion. If this is in the same process, how do I get the right result by reading the file? Many thanks.

Comment: @HuangJie I'm not recommending or condoning what you to, but to help you anyway it could be as simple as [cnicutar suggests in his or her answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35381439/440558), simply that the `fscanf` format is wrong. If you're on a 64-bit platform pointers are typically 64 bits but `int` (or `unsigned in` as `"%x"` expects) most often is still 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

`*scanf()` has no standard equivalent ot `*printf("%p", ...)`.  Code cannot read pointers is a standard way.

```
struct log_t* read_log;
//                                  problem --v
while(fscanf(fp, "Node%d's malloc address is %x", &i, &read_log) == 2){
```

---

Alternatively code can convert a pointer to an integer, then to a string, then to an integer and back to the pointer.

> **(C11) 7.20.1.4 Integer types capable of holding object pointers**

...  `intptr_t`

The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid pointer to `void` can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to `void`, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer: `uintptr_t`

These types are optional.

```
struct log_t* log = ...

// convert to uintptr_t
uintptr_t uiptr = (uintptr_t) ((void *) log);

// convert to string
char buf[100];
sprintf(buf, "%jx", (intmax_t) uiptr);

// string to iptr
uintmax_t imax;
sscanf(buf, "%jx", &imax);
uiptr = imax;

// iptr to  struct log_t*
struct log_t* log2 = ((void *) uiptr); 

assert(log == log2);
```